# How can I manipulate the way matrices multiply/divide to make their shapes match?

Tags: matrices, geometry, matrix-equations

I'm trying to manipulate the way matrices multiply/divide in order to make sure that their shapes match while using the dot product. I'm not sure how well that was explained, so here is an example. Say I have this equation: $\frac{IX}{Y}$ and I know that the shapes are the following:

$$I shape = (1000, 700)$$
$$X shape = (700,30)$$
$$Y shape = (30,10)$$

Notice : I will be using the dot product for multiplication and [Moore-Penrose Inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) for division

From this, we can notice that $I * X$ will work correctly with their shapes, and will result in the shape of $(1000, 30)$. If we go on, however, it would try to multiply $(1000, 30)$ and $(10, 30)$ because $\frac{1}{Y}$ will invert the shape. Because this doesn't work, I would change the equation to be $$(I * X) * Y^{-1}$$
where $Y^{-1}$ means that each element is inverted rather than the entire matrix. This works great for my purposes, however I will need to do this a lot with very large equations, so I want to create a program for it. To do that, I need a specific set of steps that I can follow to make the shapes match.

**EDIT:**

I just realized I forgot to put something essential in here. I want the shapes to match up, but I also want to it try to get a specific shape. In this case I would want it to go from
$$\frac{(1000,700)*(700,30)}{(30,10)}$$ to $$(1000, 10)$$

Comment: But do you want these operations to _mean_ something or any size adjustment works? For your example, the transpose would also do the trick.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but transpose should work just the same. My only problem is creating steps for it

Comment: Thinking about it again, transpose won't work. I need the answer to equal out as if it were a scalar.

Comment: It also won't work if $I$ is $1000\times700$ and $X$ is $300\times700$ or any of an infinite number of ways you can get the dimensions not to match. So why not just use matrices whose dimensions are correct for the problem? If $30\times10$ dimensions for $Y$ give you grief because the pseudoinverse is $10\times30,$ then start with a $10\times30$ matrix. The question shouldn't be how to shoehorn any given matrices into the formula, it should be how to get matrices that make sense to use the formula on.